# Center div with link elements

Tags: php, html, css, opencart

I am using a responsive custom Opencart template.I added a div element with "home,contact us,about us" links.
I am trying to center this div with three link elements but with no success.

This is my html code:

```
<div class="header-center">
 <a class="firstlink" href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><?php echo $text_home; ?></a>
        <span class="txtspacer">    |   </span>
        <a class="secondlink" href="<?php echo $contact; ?>"><?php echo $text_contact; ?></a>
        <span class="txtspacer2">    |   </span>
         <?php foreach ($informations as $information)  {
         if(in_array($information['information_id'], array(4))) {
          ?>
        <a class="thirdlink" href="<?php echo str_replace('&', '&amp;', $information['href']); ?>"><?php echo $information['title']; ?></a>
        <?php
        }
        } ?>
</div>
```

And this css code :

```
.header-center{
     display: inline-block;
     left: 10%;
     position: relative;
     top: 75px;
     font-weight:bold;
}
```

I 've tried to put margin:0 auto; and text-align:center: but it doesn't change anything.That's why i use left:10% but it doesn't display correctly for all screens.

*Sorry for my English or other mistakes is my first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't set the width of `header-center` div.
If the div's width isn't dynamic set it's width and it will work

```css
.header-center {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 230px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="header-center">
    <a class="firstlink" href="<?php echo $home; ?>">Home</a>
    <span class="txtspacer">    |   </span>
    <a class="secondlink" href="<?php echo $contact; ?>">Contact</a>
    <span class="txtspacer2">    |   </span>
    More text |
    <a class="thirdlink" href="<?php echo str_replace('&', '&amp;', $information['href']); ?>">Info</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

This might work for every width but i'm not sure if all browsers in all versions supports it:

```css
.header-center {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="header-center">
    <a class="firstlink" href="<?php echo $home; ?>">Home</a>
    <span class="txtspacer">    |   </span>
    <a class="secondlink" href="<?php echo $contact; ?>">Contact</a>
    <span class="txtspacer2">    |   </span>
    More text |
    <a class="thirdlink" href="<?php echo str_replace('&', '&amp;', $information['href']); ?>">Info</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I 've changed it and put width:613px; as another element on my template that is centered on my site and now seems to display correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you use display: inline-block; you have to apply "text-align: center;" on its parent. If you don't want to, leave it as a block, and simply use margin: auto; and apply it a defined width.

So you won't need position, left and top anymore.